# Stop Intellij IDEA from automatically indenting lines

Tags: android-intent, intellij-idea, auto-indent

I am starting to learn Java and find it extremely annoying that IDEA will automatically indent each successive line.
I would much prefer to leave me responsible for managing the indenting myself.

I have found the indent settings but don't see an option for this specifically.

Comment: Try disabling both checkbox on the following picture http://www.gamefromscratch.com/image.axd?picture=image_thumb_1657.png

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Glad to help Brian :)